# How to generate a smooth 2D travelling wave in python?

Tags: python, animation, time-series, signal-processing, sampling

I want to generate a matrix or a 2d array of size `(M*N)` where each column of the matrix (2D array in python) contain the data of a travelling sine wave, `y = sin(k*x-w*t)`. So, I use the following script, but I don't get the sine wave as smooth as of my expectation shown in [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYHHy.png). Can anyone help me how to generate very smooth sine curve by using the above formula? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
dx = np.array(x); M = len(dx)
dy = np.array(y); N = len(dy)
#** Generation of Sine wave #
t = np.linspace(1, 36, 360)
# Amplitude
amp = 5;  
# frequency
f1=20;  f2 = 10; 
# Assume the value of K, wavenumber  
k1 = 1; k2 = -2;  
rows, cols = (len(t), M)
##*********************************************
np.random.seed(12345)

arr=[]
for i in range(rows):
    col = []
    for j in range(cols):
        w = round(random.uniform(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi), 1)*f2
        d = amp * np.sin(k1*dx[j] -w*t[i]) + 2*amp * np.sin(k2*dy[j] + w*t[i])  
        col.append(d)
    arr.append(col)

sig = np.array(arr)
print('The shape of the signal :', sig.shape)#

aa=sig[:,2] # Sinusoid at 3rd column
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, aa, 'b')
plt.xlabel('location (x)')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your frequencies are way beyond your sampling rate!

Comment: @DavisHerring, thanks for the comment. Can you please check if the above approach is correct to generate time varying plane waves. In my case, I've the distance of X and Y axis that does not follow the spatial resolution. In that case what can I do? Any suggestion is appreciated.